# Jetpack Compose Desktop Change Window Title

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, desktop-application

With a Compose Desktop application the Window Title is set in the main function call. For example:

```
fun main() = application {
val state = rememberWindowState(
    placement = WindowPlacement.Floating,
    position = WindowPosition(Alignment.Center),
    isMinimized = false,
    width = 800.dp,
    height = 600.dp
)

Window(
    title = "Test Application",
    resizable = true,
    state = state,
    icon = painterResource("drawable/logo.png"),
    onCloseRequest = ::exitApplication
) {
    App()
}
```

}

I would like to add to this programatically, e.g. when the user logs in, the title would read:

```
Test Application - User Name
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is done by remembering a mutable String value and set this as a title. It looks like this:

```kotlin
fun main() = application {
    val state = rememberWindowState(
        placement = WindowPlacement.Floating,
        position = WindowPosition(Alignment.Center),
        isMinimized = false,
       width = 800.dp,
       height = 600.dp
    )
    var windowTitle by remember { mutableStateOf("Test Application") }

    Window(
        title = windowTitle,
        resizable = true,
        state = state,
        icon = painterResource("drawable/logo.png"),
        onCloseRequest = ::exitApplication
    ) {
        App()
    }
}
```

later you can then change the title by just calling

```
windowTitle = "Test Application - $userName"
```